# How to query using an array which matches with a single element in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo DB documents as below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5dd3917c7e741b023cd0bda3"),
    "username": "user1",
    "location": "abc"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5dd3917c7e741b023cd0bda4"),
    "username": "user2",
    "location": "def"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5dd54702a4cc7508adbde0f1"),
    "username": "user3",
    "location": "abc"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5dd546dfa4cc7508adbde0f0"),
    "username": "user4",
    "location": "ghi"
}
```

How can I find/query documents matching an anyone of the element inside this array ["abc", "def"] with MongoDB document field location?

Thanks